# Replace variable in mathjax equation

Tags: javascript, jquery, mathjax

Say I have an equation

```
\(x+y = z\\)
```

in MathJaX, and I want to replace the $x$ and $y$ numbers from a user input, and calculate a $z$ given those two. How would I go about doing this?

I know that if I turn the equation into

```
<div id='x'>\({}\)</div>\(+\)<div id='y'>\({}\)</div>\(=\)<div id='z'>\({}\)</div>
```

I can use MathJax.Hub.getAllJax("x")[0], MathJax.Hub.getAllJax("y")[0], and MathJax.Hub.getAllJax("z")[0] to replace the content of each id by a number. This, however, seems like an awfully complicated expression, and I if there was a way to make it simpler; for instance if it's possible to write

```
\(class{x}{}+\class{y}{}=\class{z}{}\)
```

and replace each class with a number. I don't know if this is possible, or if there are any other ways of doing it. in either case:

How do I replace parts of a MathJaX equation (a variable) with a user-specified number?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/9BCGx/30/

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI not quite what I need, I don't need to change the entire expression, just x and y.

Comment: Not really an answer but this is generally a bad idea. First, TeX is a notation for visual layout, not a semantic or procedural notation, i.e., it is the wrong choice for calculating things. Second, editing MathJax output is ill advised (though it might appear to work for very simple changes like replacing one digit with another); if you change the underlying source you generally have to rerender the entire equation (e.g., adding to a numerator might change the fraction line). You are better off using something like mathjs as an internal model and use MathJax only to render mathjs TeX output.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger The calculation will be done before the rendering of course, but it would be a nicer-looking calculator if the symbols are rendered.

Comment: This is not a bad idea, it's definitely useful to do this. It's just doesn't seem to have an elegant way to do this today.